# How to add a counter with row numbering on all site in mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

I want to add an automatic numbering of order items to all pages.
Below is an example that works but only numbers on one page. After going to the next page, it starts from the beginning.

```
public ActionResult ListaZlecen(int? IdStatusZlecenia, int strona = 1)
        {
            var ListaZlecenWszystkich = db.Zlecenia.ToList();
            var userId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
            //var ListaZlecen = db.Zlecenia.Where(p => p.UserId == userId).ToList();
            //var ListaZlecen = db.Zlecenia.OrderBy(w => w.IdZlecenia).Where(p => p.UserId == userId).Skip((strona - 1) * WielkoscStrony).Take(WielkoscStrony).ToList();
            var ListaZlecen = db.Zlecenia.OrderBy(w => w.IdZlecenia).Skip((strona - 1) * WielkoscStrony).Take(WielkoscStrony).ToList();
            //   var zleceniezalacznik = db.ZleceniaZalaczniki.ToList();

            var viewodel = new ListaZlecenUzytkownikaViewModel()
            {
                StronaInfo = new StronaInfo
                {

                    AktualnaStrona = strona,
                    PozycjeNaStrone = WielkoscStrony,
                    WszystkiePozycje = ListaZlecenWszystkich.Count()

                },
                ListaZlecenUzytkownika = ListaZlecen
            };

            return View(viewodel);
        }
```

and View

```
@model AplikacjaHelpDesk.ViewModels.ListaZlecenUzytkownikaViewModel
@using AplikacjaHelpDesk.Infrastructure;

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Lista Zlecen Użytkownika";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_LayoutAdministracja.cshtml";
}


<div class="container-fluid">
    <img src="~/Content/Images/Layout/Home.png" />
    <a href="link">
        @Html.MvcSiteMap().SiteMapPath()
    </a>
    <h2><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>&nbsp<strong>Lista Zleceń </strong></h2>
    <br /><br />
    <div id="divLoading" class="panel panel-primary text-center text-primary" style="display:none;">
        <h3><strong>Proszę czekać ładowane są posty!</strong></h3>
    </div>
    <div id="divLoadingForm" class="panel panel-primary text-center text-primary" style="display:none;">
        <h3><strong>Proszę czekać ładuję formularz</strong></h3>
    </div>
    @*@if (ViewBag.Informacja != null)
                {
            <div class="alert alert-warning"><h4><strong>@TempData["Dodano-Post"]</strong></h4></div>
        }*@

    <table class="table table-responsive table-striped transactions" style="text-combine-upright:all;">
        <tr style="text-transform: uppercase; text-combine-upright:all;">
            <th>
                <label>Pozycja Nr.</label>
            </th>
            <th>
                <label>Nr Zlecenia</label>
            </th>
            <th>
                <label>Data Przyjęcia Zlecenia</label>
            </th>
            <th>
                <label>Data Planowanego Zakończenia Zlecenia</label>
            </th>
            <th>
                <label>Data zakończenia zlecenia</label>
            </th>
            <th style="width: 160px;"></th>
            <th style="width: 160px;"></th>
        </tr>
        @{ var i = 0;}
        @foreach (var item in Model.ListaZlecenUzytkownika)
        {

            <tr class="panel panel-primary">
                @*
                        <h5><strong>Zlecenie nr: @Html.DisplayFor(modeItem => item.IdZlecenia)</strong></h5>

                <td>
                        @{i++;}
                        @i
                </td>
                <td>
                    <h5><strong>Zlecenie nr: @Html.DisplayFor(modeItem => item.IdZlecenia)</strong></h5>
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DataPrzyjeciaZlecenia)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DataPlanowaniaZakonczenia)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DataZakonczenia)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Ajax.ActionLink("Pokaż Posty Zlecenia", "_ListaPostow", new { idZlecenia = @item.IdZlecenia }, new AjaxOptions()
               {
                   HttpMethod = "GET",
                   LoadingElementId = "divLoading",
                   UpdateTargetId = "divPozycje",
                   InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace

               }, new { @class = "btn btn-primary" })
                </td>
                <td>


                    @Ajax.ActionLink("Dodaj Odpowiedz", "_DodajPost", new { idZlecenia = @item.IdZlecenia }, new AjaxOptions()
               {
                   HttpMethod = "GET",
                   LoadingElementId = "divLoadingForm",
                   UpdateTargetId = "divDodajPozycje",
                   InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace

               }, new { @class = "btn btn-primary" })
                </td>

            </tr>
            <tr style="background: #23527c; color:white;">
                <td>
                    <label>Opis załącznika</label>
                </td>
                <td style="width: 120px;">
                    <label>Załącznik</label>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="panel panel-group">
                <td>
                    @Html.Raw(item.ZleceniaZalaczniki.Opis)
                </td>
                <td>
                    <span class="btn btn-primary">
                        @Html.ActionLink("Pobierz", "Download", "Zlecenia", new { nazwaPliku = @item.ZleceniaZalaczniki.NazwaPliku }, null)
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-download" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    </span>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr id="divDodajPozycje"></tr>
        }
    </table>

    <br />
    <div class="btn-group pull-right">
        @Html.LinkStrony(Model.StronaInfo, x => Url.Action("ListaZlecen", new { strona = x }))
    </div>
    <br />
    <hr />
    <div id="divPozycje">

    </div>
</div>
```

I tried this way but it creates numbering only on one page. Going to the next numbering is created from the beginning.

```
 @{ var i = 0;}
 <td>
    @{i++;}
    @i
 </td>
```

I have 3 orders on each page and I would like all orders to be automatically numbered, for example:
First page 1,2,3
Second page 4,5,6

I am asking for help in creating the numbering for the entire collection of orders

Comment: You have put here too much code in the question and I think most of it is irrelevant. It is not helpful to be able to understand your problem.

Comment: However. If what you want to achieve is pagination. Then you need to save the page number and pass it from one page to another, using a cookie, or session. Then use the page number to figure our the right numbering for the orders

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of starting at i=0 you can start at your current page,

I don't know which language it is but I hope i got it right.

```
// Instead of this: @{ var i = 0;} - on your view
//Use this:
@{ var i = (Model.AktualnaStrona -1 ) * Model.PozycjeNaStrone ;}

//It should be equal to the calculation you use on the API:
(strona - 1) * WielkoscStrony

//(from this line: )
var ListaZlecen = db.Zlecenia.OrderBy(w => w.IdZlecenia).
Skip((strona - 1) * WielkoscStrony). //--> THIS
Take(WielkoscStrony).ToList();
```